# opening a new page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my web application I have a button when I click I want to open a new page, the page should width 220, height 300 like this please help me thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like

```
 onclick="window.open('default.aspx','','height=300,width:220,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=0,left=0,status=yes');"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you achive this using javascript.

http://javascript.internet.com/generators/popup-window.html

Answer (score 1):

Use

[window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Window.open)

> Creates a new secondary browser window
>   and loads the referenced resource.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you

```
window.open(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + "standard asp.net relative URL including parameters", "_blank", "width=220, height=300, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, menubar=yes, location=no");
```